# Pandas groupby output to Excel using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Following on from an earlier question, I am trying to output some mean values calculated from a `groupby function` on a pandas `DataFrame`.  I have seen a lot of examples for writing whole `DataFrames` to an excel but I haven't found examles of writing a single pandas mean output to excel having run a `groupby` or even a describe function on a `dataframe`

My current `groupby function` is the following:

```
DF[(DF['Iteration'] == CURRENTLOG_ID) & (DF['Feature Enabled'] == 1)].groupby([’Feature Active'])[['Value1','Value2']].mean()
```

And I would then print to screen using:

```
print np.round(FeatureON, decimals=1)
```

This would output the following to `cmd window` ...

```
                                Value1   Value2
Feature Enabled    Iteration
1                  Iteration_1  -1276.3  -1302.9
```

I just wanted to know if there is a simple way of writing the mean outputs `-1276.3` and `-1302.9`  to `Excel` using combined `Pandas+xlsxwriter`, or is this best done individually without the `groupby function`?

Thanks

Comment: It isn't clear, to me, what you want to do. Do you want the mean values to Excel without the headers and index columns? Or do you want to do the equivalent of `groupby()` in Excel via xlsxwriter? Perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: There is a [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel) method for a df, so you can do this either on the result of the groupby, or call `reset_index` on it and then call `to_excel`

Comment: Thanks for the to_excel hint, I have managed to get a working output to my excel file, but just to confirm jmcnamara's question, I was wondering if it is possible to split the FeatureON output without the headers and just print the last row of text >>>>  
    1                  Iteration_1  -1276.3  -1302.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to write the dataframe to Excel without the headers and/or the index using options to the [`to_excel()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) pandas method as follows:

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=False, index=False)
```

See also [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_pandas.html).

Comment: Thanks jmcnamara, got it to work, this was what I was looking for. Cheers